# Distributing complex conjugate

Tags: output-formatting, complex

If you have a statement like:

```
Conjugate[a+b]
```

you get back

```
Conjugate[a+b]
```

but I'm expecting

```
Conjugate[a]+Conjugate[b]
```

If you try the logical comparison:

```
Conjugate[a+b]==Conjugate[a]+Conjugate[b]
```

You get the same result back (it does not evaluate the expression).

I'm assuming that Mathematica must not have enough information to give me the result I'm expecting, but I am not sure what I need to tell it. Could someone please explain to me what I am missing from my states?

Edit: I found a workaround but it is definitely not my preferred method.

```
Map[Conjugate, a+b]
```

will output as expected. I don't think this would be a preferred method because I'm not sure what it would do in all cases.

Comment: To add to this, if you do a transformation rule like `Conjugate[a+b]==Conjugate[a]+Conjugate[b] /. {a->I, b->2}` the expression evaluates to true

Comment: `FullSimplify[Conjugate[a + b] == Conjugate[a] + Conjugate[b] ]` ?

Comment: @kevin:  But surely the OP wants the result for the general form $a = x + i y$, etc.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Sorry that was me posting extra info on my question, my point was that obvious when real values are used it works as expected, so why when left as symbols does it not work as expected.

Comment: @kglr that returns true! but if you do `FullSimplify[Conjugate[a+b]]` you get the same result back :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Distribute`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Distribute.html).

```
Distribute[Conjugate[a + b]]
(* Conjugate[a] + Conjugate[b] *)
```

A safer version is

```
Distribute[Conjugate[a + b], Plus]
```

It will only distribute over `Plus`.

This is even safer:

```
Distribute[Conjugate[a + b], Plus, Conjugate]
```

As for `Conjugate[a+b]==Conjugate[a]+Conjugate[b]`: don't think of `==` as an operator that *does* something.  Instead, it *represents* an equality.  Testing if the equality will hold for all parameter values is complicated and time consuming.  Having `==` do it automatically would be counterproductive (it would make simple operations take a long time). Thus you need to do this manually:

```
Conjugate[a + b] == Conjugate[a] + Conjugate[b] // FullSimplify
(* True *)
```

Comment: Thanks! this was exactly what I needed.

Comment: Is there a way to do this for a more complicated expression? Say F[(a+b)*] where F is explicitly typed out and may be arbitrarily complicated.

Comment: `Map[ Distribute[#, Plus, Conjugate]&, %, Infinity] ` seems to do the trick in one test case ... not sure if it's completely stable though.